# Java calculate max customer price using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a problem with streams. I have many `Customer` objects and I would like to calculate which one of them paid the most.

This is my sample data:

```
class Orders {

    private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

    public void prepareData() {

        Product socks = new ProductBuilder()
                .setPrice(new BigDecimal("23"))
                .setCategory(Category.C)
                .setName("SOCKS")
                .build();

        Product jacket = new ProductBuilder()
                .setPrice(new BigDecimal("199"))
                .setCategory(Category.A)
                .setName("JACKET")
                .build();

        Product watch = new ProductBuilder()
                .setPrice(new BigDecimal("100"))
                .setCategory(Category.B)
                .setName("WATCH CASIO")
                .build();


        Customer john = new CustomerBuilder()
                .setAge(18)
                .setName("JOHN")
                .setSurname("JOHNSON")
                .setEmail("john@johnson.com")
                .build();

        Customer mike = new CustomerBuilder()
                .setAge(20)
                .setName("MIKE")
                .setSurname("MAX")
                .setEmail("mike@max.com")
                .build();


        Order orderJohn = new OrderBuilder()
                .setQuantity(2)
                .setCustomer(john)
                .setProduct(watch)
                .setOrderDate(LocalDate.now())
                .build();

        Order orderJohn2 = new OrderBuilder()
                .setQuantity(4)
                .setCustomer(john)
                .setProduct(socks)
                .setOrderDate(LocalDate.now())
                .build();


         Order orderMike = new OrderBuilder()
                .setQuantity(2)
                .setCustomer(mike)
                .setProduct(jacket)
                .setOrderDate(LocalDate.now())
                .build();

        orders.add(orderJohn);
        orders.add(orderJohn2);
        orders.add(orderMike);
    }
}
```

Now I should group by customer because one customer has many orders and calculate price * and quantity and select maximum using `orders.stream()`? How can I do that?

My class definitions:

```
public class Order {

    private Customer customer;
    private Product product;
    private int quantity;
    private LocalDate orderDate;
   //get/set
}
public class Customer {

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private int age;
    private String email;
    //get/set
}
public class Product {
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private Category category;
    //get/set
}
```

And builders

```
    public class CustomerBuilder {

        private Customer customer = new Customer();

        public CustomerBuilder setName(String name){
            customer.setName(name);
            return this;
        }

        public CustomerBuilder setSurname(String surname){
            customer.setSurname(surname);
            return this;
        }

        public CustomerBuilder setAge(int age){
            customer.setAge(age);
            return this;
        }

        public CustomerBuilder setEmail(String email){
            customer.setEmail(email);
            return this;
        }

        public Customer build()  {

            return customer;
        }

    }
public class OrderBuilder {
   private Order order = new Order();

   public OrderBuilder setCustomer(Customer customer){
       order.setCustomer(customer);
       return this;
   }

   public OrderBuilder setProduct(Product product){
       order.setProduct(product);
       return this;
   }

   public OrderBuilder setQuantity(int quantity){
       order.setQuantity(quantity);
       return this;
   }

   public OrderBuilder setOrderDate(LocalDate orderDate){
       order.setOrderDate(orderDate);
       return this;
   }

   public Order build(){
       return order;
   }

}
public class ProductBuilder {

    private Product product = new Product();

    public ProductBuilder setCategory(Category category){
        product.setCategory(category);
        return this;
    }

    public ProductBuilder setName(String name){
        product.setName(name);
        return this;
    }

    public ProductBuilder setPrice(BigDecimal bigDecimal){
        product.setPrice(bigDecimal);
        return this;
    }

    public Product build() {
        return product;
    }
}
```

Comment: Will be easier if you include your class definitions (order, product, and customer)

Comment: as well as providing the expected outcome.

Comment: You could use `.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(o -> o.getCustomer))`

Comment: @ernest_k I added class definitions

Comment: @lukassz we need an example that we can easily copy and paste and try out, just those classes won't really help. Simplify your Order and Customer to something smaller that just has the minimal values.

Comment: @jbx I added rest of classes

Comment: what is the expected result? `Map<String, Order>`? if so, what is the `String` - how it is computed?

Comment: or may be you want the customer that spends the most?

Comment: @Eugene I would like to display just Customer that paid most with final cost

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following finds the top customer by first grouping by the `customer` field (mapped to the total of corresponding purchase value [`quantity * price`]).

The result of that aggregation is then traversed to find "max" by total purchase value.

```
Customer topCustomer = orders.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Order::getCustomer,
                Collectors.mapping(
                        order -> order.getProduct()
                                      .getPrice()
                                      .multiply(new BigDecimal(order.getQuantity())),
                        Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add))))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue))
        .map(Entry::getKey)
        .orElse(null);
```

It's important to note that this assumes `hashCode()` and `equals()` are properly overridden in `Customer` for the grouping to work correctly.

EDIT:

If the total amount of purchases is also required, you will need to get the full entry instead of mapping to just the key (below code is based on snippet above):

```
Optional<Entry<Customer, BigDecimal>> topCustomerEntry = orders.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Order::getCustomer,
                Collectors.mapping(order -> 
                    order.getProduct()
                            .getPrice()
                            .multiply(new BigDecimal(order.getQuantity())),
                Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add))))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .max(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue));

BigDecimal topValue = null; //total value for top customer
Customer customer = null;   //customer with most purchases

if(topCustomerEntry.isPresent()) {
    topValue = topCustomerEntry.get().getValue();
    customer = topCustomerEntry.get().getKey();
}
```

This will just print the values. But you can restructure the code to assign them to a variable.

Comment: you can do a very tiny simplification IMO via `.max(Entry.comparingByValue())`

Comment: @ernest_k ok, but how can I get final price?

Comment: @lukassz I didn't include that as it wasn't in your question. I'll edit the answer

Comment: @ernest_k when I assign `ifPresent` into variable should I use `Optional`? Like this `Optional<Map.Entry<Customer, BigDecimal>>` is propper way?

Comment: @ernest_k I have one more question. I would like to display the date in which there were the most orders and the least. How can I do it?

Comment: @lukassz You can just group by date (`groupingBy(Order::getOrderDate`). Then after  that, change second stream to: `...entrySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(e -> e.getValued().size())).collect(Collectors.toList())`. Now that will give a list where first element will have the least amount and the last element with the most. The key will be the date and the value, the actual min/max value.

Comment: @ernest_k  Great, it works. Can you look on my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52801589/java-calculate-discount-on-order-stream-condition ?

Comment: The solution works perfectly, can i have some help please? The order currently  has a product and a customer, what are the changes to the above java 8 stream if there is a set of products instead?

Answer (score 2):

In case you need the customer which spends the most (by email for example):

```
  orders.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    x -> x.getCustomer().getEmail(),
                    x -> x.getProduct().getPrice().multiply(new BigDecimal(x.getQuantity())),
                    BigDecimal::add))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .max(Entry.comparingByValue())
            .ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Maybe using e-mail address instead of name is better, b/c the names could be the same.

Comment: Nice - looks so easy. I have to exercise the streams ASAP. +1 from me

Comment: Why not use `Collectors.groupingBy()` ?

Comment: @jbx the other answer uses that, take a look; could have been done like that too, I guess